# list not showing inside fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having the following fragment. It is supposed to show the list CountingList.counting. But it does not. I can not find the error. Can anybody spot the error. It worked before i added the floating button. But it did not update properly and sometimes it did not show up.

fragmentCurrentCounting.kt

```
class TripDataFragment : Fragment() {

    private var columnCount = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        var test = CountingList.countings
        super.onResume()

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)

        val myRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)

        // Set the adapter
        if (myRecyclerView is RecyclerView) {
            with(myRecyclerView) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                adapter = MyTripDataRecyclerViewAdapter(CountingList.countings)
            }
        }

        return view
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
        const val ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(columnCount: Int) =
            TripDataFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

fragment_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="sendButtonClick">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.db.passengercounting.TripDataFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".TripDataFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send_mail"
        android:onClick="sendButtonClick"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
        tools:context=".TripDataFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AddButtonClick Code in the MainActivity:

```
    fun AddButtonClick(view:View)
    {
        // TODO: fix this
        var departureTime = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.DepartureTime).text
...
        var hints = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Hints).text

        try {
            //TODO: fix this
            val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")

            var newItem = Counting(
                formatter.parse(date),
...
                hints.toString()
            )

            CountingList.countings.add(newItem)
        }
        catch (ex:Exception)
        {
            println(ex.message)
        }

        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "saved " + CountingList.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val myRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)

        myRecyclerView?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: how this can be true if (view is RecyclerView) {

Comment: Kindly check the context you are passing. I think you should pass `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line of code

```
if (view is RecyclerView){
...
}
```

as I can see in your XML file the root view is `RelativeLayout` so when you inflate that layout file in this line

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)
```

the type of `view` is RelativeLayout and because of that the condition of `if (view is RecyclerView)` is never true.

you can use `findViewById` to access your RecyclerView, like this:

```
myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

the better solution is to use `ViewBinding` when using xml.

Comment: The list is now showing. But it does not update when i add new elements

Comment: can I see your code?
do you call ```notifyDataSetChanged()``` on your RecyclerView adapter after adding data?

Comment: I added the code where i am adding the data. I am doing that in the MainActivity. I am not sure if that is the right place. But i am new to android development and that was the only place were the function got discovered. Dont know why

Comment: I put a notifyDataSetChanged in the onResume Function of the Fragment and that updates the ui correctly, but it really seems to be really hacky

Comment: create a global instance of your RecyclerView adapter and use that instead of ```myRecyclerView?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()```.
i think that will fix your problem.

Comment: the ```myRecyclerView=view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)``` in your ```AddButtonClick()``` function will always return null and that's because you trying to find RecyclerView inside of a Button!!

Comment: okay, that was just a quick try to see if it changes something. Good point thanks!!

Comment: did your problem solve?

Comment: well, i just call it in onResume() but thats not the clean solutions in my eyes

Comment: read the two last of my comments,  I just tell you what to do.